# como utilizar los iconos de family=Material+Icons sin tener que utilizarlo desde la web

Tags: enlace

tengo este problema sencillo, descargue el paquete de  family=Material+Icons para mi plantilla AdminBSBMaterialDesign-master y necesito incluir estos iconos en mi plantilla base para poder usarlos:

Welcome To | Bootstrap Based Admin Template - Material Design

```
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="{{ asset('plantilla/bootswatch/themes/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Bootstrap Core Css -->
<link href="{{ asset('plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Waves Effect Css -->
<link href="plugins/node-waves/waves.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Animation Css -->
<link href="plugins/animate-css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Morris Chart Css-->
<link href="plugins/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Custom Css -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- AdminBSB Themes. You can choose a theme from css/themes instead of get all themes -->
<link href="css/themes/all-themes.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

algo parecido a las etiquetas que se encuentran debajo que hacen referencia a un directorio local.Por ejemplo lo que hago en  Bootstrap Core Css que me funciona ok.
Por favor necesito que me respondan lo antes posible. Gracias!!!

Comment: Podrias cambiar la imagen del codigo por codigo en texto

Comment: ya está puesto el código en texto...gracias, estaré pendiente por si encuentras alguna solución...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder utilizar el recurso de manera local en tu proyecto debes realizar lo siguiente:

1.- Acceder al repositorio alojado en **GitHub** [Repositorio](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/iconfont) y descargar el archivo `material-icons.css` y guardarlo en una carpeta.

2.- Posteriormente descargar estos tres archivos.

MaterialIcons-Regular.eot
MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf
MaterialIcons-Regular.woff
MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2

Tu archivo descargado `material-icons.css` debe de estar forma:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local('Material Icons'),
       local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
       url(MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
       url(MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;

  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

> **Nota:** El archivo .css y los 4 archivos descargados deben de estar en la misma carpeta.

Podras acceder al recurso de esta forma (**ejemplo**):

```
<link href="{{ asset('plugins/Material Icons/material-icons.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Espero que sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias es que me faltó poner dentro de la misma carpeta el archivo css junto al resto de los archivos. Me funcionó...un placer

Comment: De nada me da gusto que te funcionara, puedes marcarla como aceptada para que le sirva de ayuda a los demás que cuentan con la misma duda. ¡saludos!.[Como aceptar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas)